# The value of the prop I send does not change. if it's successfully logged in, prop must be true in navbar.I'm getting 200 ok from the backend

Tags: reactjs

I set isLoggedIn to in this code .

Login.js

`` ` ``

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {  NavLink,useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function LoginPage() {
  const [username,setUsername]=useState("")
  const [password,setPassword]=useState("")
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLogged] = useState(false)
 
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function checkInformations(){
    axios.post("/api/auth/login",{
      username :username,
      password:password
    })
    .then(response=>{
      if(response.status===200){
        setIsLogged(true)
        console.log("Success")
        navigate("/")
      }
      
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.error("Request error: ",error)
      setWarning(true)
    });

  }

  function handleLoginClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInformations()
    
  }


  return (
    <div className="grid min-h-screen place-items-center  font-body ">
           
            ...
                    <button onClick={handleLoginClick}   type="submit" >
                        Login
                    </button>

            ...           
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}
```

`` ` ``

App.js

I set it to false at first and then in login.js I set it to true if the login is successful.Here I am transferring data between components.

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLogged] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div >
      <Navbar isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} /> 
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage setIsLogged={setIsLogged} />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

export default function Navbar(props) {   const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;

and this is how I finally get the props. but prop of isLoggedIn cannot be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have correctly initialized the isLoggedIn useState on the top-level(App.js) and also passed it to the Login.js

However, the issue is that instead of using the setIsLogged you are passing from App.js you are reinitializing it on Login.js

So basically on your code, you are updating the incorrect useState inside the Login.js

The fixed code should look like this:

App.js (No change needed)

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLogged] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div >
      <Navbar isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} /> 
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage setIsLogged={setIsLogged} />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Login.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {  NavLink,useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function LoginPage(props) {
  const [username,setUsername]=useState("")
  const [password,setPassword]=useState("")
 
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function checkInformations(){
    axios.post("/api/auth/login",{
      username :username,
      password:password
    })
    .then(response=>{
      if(response.status===200){
        props.setIsLogged(true)
        console.log("Success")
        navigate("/")
      }
      
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.error("Request error: ",error)
      setWarning(true)
    });

  }

  function handleLoginClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInformations()
    
  }


  return (
    <div className="grid min-h-screen place-items-center  font-body ">
           
            ...
                    <button onClick={handleLoginClick}   type="submit" >
                        Login
                    </button>

            ...           
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}
```